# Minecraft 2x3 flush block swap - no observer blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I need help with building a 2x3 block swap without using observers or comparators, in java edition (1.15.2).

1x1 floor swap (functional)
[image: example I found online]

1x1 wall swap (functional)
[image: another example I found online]

I need to build this on a server that has no access to nether quartz (so no observer block and no comparator), but repeaters, slime blocks, honey blocks are okay. Any help would be appreciated, I've never been good with redstone devices, and this seems like a complicated task, even if I was good with redstone. Maybe I'm overthinking it?

Update: a bit of progress with this tutorial

(images below), even though this is an old tutorial, it is functional on java edition version 1.15.2.

Test 1 from tutorial (functional)
[image: test 1 top view]
[image: test 1 back view]

Test 2 from tutorial (functional)
[image: test 2 top]
[image: test 2 back view]

These blocks being swapped are not beside each other though

Comment: The contraption in the first image is at least rotation dependent. Maybe you wanted one of the repeaters on a different setting?

Comment: The first two work fine, the third one I was having problems with

Comment: Try this video  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=06q6FkYTwGo

Comment: Note that redstone works very differently in MCBE than in MCJava, especially pistons have a lot of bugs unique to both editions and the redstone update order is different, so that might very well not help. But maybe it does, I haven't tried it.

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work in Java edition

Comment: might return to this soon, thanks for the update!

Answer (score -1):

Yep, it’s really this easy: (see pic)[image]

Comment: This is not flush with either wall or floor.